# Clickonce - How to add an image to installer?

Tags: installation, clickonce, customization

Is it possible to change the GUI of a Clickonce installer? To add a custom image for example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope. You can change the icon, but that's it.

This is intentional, because ClickOnce allows you to install stuff from the web, and allowing UI changes opens the door to people with malicious intent. Using the same UI for every clickonce install makes sure people know that something is being installed: you can't have the UI mock a standard message box for example, while actually installing software in the background (without the user knowing).